# Will the <center> tag ever be phased out of HTML?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I've always used the `<center>` tag when I center text in HTML. Recently though, I've gotten backlash for using that instead of using CSS for text alignment. The main reason people have for not using it is that the `<center>` tag is antiquated and will be "phased out". Is this true? Should I start moving my text alignment to CSS? Or am I safe with just using the `<center>` tag?

Comment: This feature [ <center> ] is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.
 Source :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @qiangong2 in html5 we dont use this tag and now people use css or in bootstrap class text-center

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the beginning there was HTML and it was good.

Then the need to change how HTML was presented arose and HTML grew to encompass presentational elements such as `<center>` `<b>` `<i>` and everyone rejoiced... "yayyyyy"

Then people began to realise that what they had wrought was ugly: "boooooo" and they rejected these presentational elements and instead spawned a new entity called CSS. CSS could control the presentation while maintaining separation from the structure, promoting reuse, consistency and faster development and all was good and there was much merriment.

Now HTML and CSS live in harmony and presentational elements wallow in the grimy grimness that is deprecation.

Comment: Sounds like a story from a book or something. "HTML: The saga" lol

Comment: This *"yayyyyy"*  should definitely be wrapped inside a [<blink>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the laugh :D

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `<b>` and `<i>` grew up to be semantic after all, or perhaps were semantic from the very beginning: `<b>` marking up "keywords" (as in dictionaries or glossaries), and `<i>` signalling an "alternative voice" (as for shifted meaning or different language). What basically aligns with usage of bold and italic font faces in typography pretty much predating HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you should change to CSS. The `<center>` tag has been deprecated since HTML 4 (and XHTML 1) in favor of the CSS `text-align` property.

Answer (score 2):

`<center>` tag is obsolete. [REF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,
>   its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to
>   avoid using it.

This tag has been deprecated in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1) in favor of the CSS `text-align` property, which can be applied to the `<div>` element or to an individual `<p>`. For centering blocks, use other CSS properties like `margin-left` and `margin-right` and set them to auto (or set `margin` to 0 auto).

Check [here](https://caniuse.com/) to see which tags can be used.

[image]